# Passing variables of bash script to another bash script for submitting job on queue

Tags: linux, bash, c++11

I tried to read my file, the device (GPU or CPU), and the size of my vector from command line and then with respect to the chosen device, submit my job script with that parameters in to the queue of specific GPU or CPU. But after submitting my job to the queue, when I validate my script like:

bash job.sh

I saw that my parameters file, device, and size from submitjob.sh script did not pass to the job.sh script.

Could you please help me what is my mistake?!

My submitjob.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh -f
echo "Input The File!";
read file
echo "Choose Gpu Or Cpu!";
read device
echo "Input Vector Size!";
read size
echo
if [ "$device" = "Gpu" ]; then
qsub -I -l nodes=1:gen9:ppn=2 -d . ./job.sh file device size
else
qsub -I -l nodes=1:skl:ppn=2 -d . ./job.sh file device size
fi
```

---

my job.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

source /opt/intel/inteloneapi/setvars.sh

echo
echo start: $(date "+%y%m%d.%H%M%S.%3N")
echo
$file $device $size
echo
echo stop: $(date "+%y%m%d.%H%M%S.%3N")
echo
```

Comment: Where could `bash job.sh` get the arguments from?

Comment: in fact I wanted to pass the argument from submitJob script to the job.sh

Comment: The arguments to the script are in `"$@"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to to put `$` before the variables in `submitjob.sh`:

```
qsub -I -l nodes=1:gen9:ppn=2 -d . ./job.sh "$file" "$device" "$size"
```

Then in `job.sh`, you get the arguments from `$1`, `$2`, etc.

```
#!/bin/bash

source /opt/intel/inteloneapi/setvars.sh
file=$1
device=$2
size=$3

echo
echo start: $(date "+%y%m%d.%H%M%S.%3N")
echo
"$file" "$device" "$size"
echo
echo stop: $(date "+%y%m%d.%H%M%S.%3N")
echo
```

Comment: Thank you, after bash submitJob.sh, when I do bash job.sh  it troughs an error which is command not find.

Comment: The problem is arguments from submitJob does not pass to the job .sh

Comment: The line `$file $device $size` tries to execute the value of `$file` as a command. Is that what it's supposed to be?